# Игнорирование треугольных скобок

Tags: java, html, html5

Есть код:

```
<div id="bg"><p>ArrayList<String></p> </div>
```

ArrayList `<String>` - динамический массив в Java и String - тип данных, который указывается в скобках треугольных скобках, но при запуске сайта `<String>` исчезает, так как оно думает, что это тэг.
Как можно игнорировать `<String>` что бы он отображался на сайте со скобками и с текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть `&lt;` благодаря которому создаеться треугольная скобка